CloudWatch Logs creating new FireLens log streams on every ECS deployment
I'm using AWS ECS with FireLens to route container logs to CloudWatch Logs. My ECS task definition includes a container that uses awsfirelens as the log driver and another container running Fluent Bit for log forwarding. Below is a snippet of my ECS task definition:
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "ecs-dev-container",
        "image": "xxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/image:latest",
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awsfirelens"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "log_router",
        "image": "xxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/custom/fluentbit:dev",
        "firelensConfiguration": {
            "type": "fluentbit",
            "options": {
                "config-file-type": "file",
                "config-file-value": "/fluent-bit/alt/fluent-bit.conf"
            }
        },
        "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "log_router_group",
                    "awslogs-region": "ap-northeast-2",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "dev"
                }
            },
    }
]

My Fluent Bit configuration is as follows:
[OUTPUT]
    name cloudwatch_logs
    match *
    region ap-northeast-2
    log_group_name /dev/log
    log_stream_prefix log_
    log_stream_template $date
    auto_create_group true

The issue I'm facing is that every time I deploy my ECS service, a new log stream is created in CloudWatch Logs, even if there haven't been any significant changes to the service. Over time, this results in a large number of log streams, which makes it difficult to manage and monitor logs.
Question:
Is there a way to prevent all deployments from creating a new log stream of the format 'log_ecs-dev-container-firelens-f8e3692ac6574537895466ab5b882e42' other than $date?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

No, you can't change this. Each ECS task will have it's own log stream. Format will be,
<awslogs-stream-prefix>/<container_name>/<task_id>

However, what you can do is group your log streams based on your needs by adding additional information to the prefix. Like, image name or tag as mentioned here.
